# On page scroll down show static content from json array

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON Array. I have total 1000 ids and 1000 cities. Initially I have to load 100 ids and cities. After scroll down the page I have to load another 100 ids and cities like that. I have to load all. How to load ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var json=[];
var json=[{"id":1,"city":"bangalore"},
          {"id":2,"city":"chennai"}
      ];
$(function() {
    $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    document.write(obj.id+"<br>");
</script>



</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you find the answer helpful accept it, otherwise tell if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(document).height() == $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
       // another load
   }
});
```

When event scroll occurs script checks if we are at the end of the page.

Comment: for few cities we can do like this..but i can't write for 1000 again and again

Comment: Do you really need to send city name? if so, you'll have to create such a big array and send it's parts. Preferably I'd change server side code so it would only need id, then iterate. Additionally, code You presented lacks " }):" at the end of the <script>